# Adding a button to the UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I want to add an image to my navigationBar, but I can't get it done properly. This is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnStateChange: UIBarButtonItem!
    let buttonState: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    buttonState.setImage(UIImage(named: "Button-State.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonState.addTarget(self, action: nil, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    buttonState.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)
    
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: buttonState)
    self.btnStateChange = barButton
```

It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

But I get this result:

[image]

Do I need to change the code? Or is it possibly the PNG I use?

Comment: Most of the code seems unnecessary, does `UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Button-State.png")))` work?

Comment: but how can an UIImage be added to a customView?

Comment: Made a slight correction, it'll need to be a uiimageview

Comment: Well.. It reduced the code dramatically, but still shows the above shown white square

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If green colour is a part of the png image, you probably need to set rendering mode as `.AlwaysOriginal` for the `UIImage`.

```
let buttonState: UIButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
buttonState.setImage(UIImage(named: "Button-State.png")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
buttonState.addTarget(self, action: nil, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
buttonState.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)
```